# Uploading external scripts as part of chef cookbook and execute

Tags: chef-infra

Is there any options to upload our own external scripts (say *.sh, *.bat, *.ps1) as part of Chef cookbook and execute during chef-client run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it either as [template](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html) or as [cookbook_file](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_cookbook_file.html), then call it using the [bash](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_bash.html) or [execute](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html) resource.

Comment: Thank you!! Have used cookbook_file and it worked :)